# How to roll back previous history of the file git vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How to reload the previous history of the file in git source control in vscode?
vs code provides to restore only last commit and I can see all the history of the file with "Git History" extension in vscode but is there any way to roll back to any history of the file?

Comment: You just want to checkout to a previous commit?

Comment: yes! I can checkout to last commit but not any commit before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to checkout a previous commit, I recommend to do it using command line:

- hit `ctrl + j` to open up a terminal in VSCode
- type `git log` to see commit history (or you can do that by looking the commit history from repo's page, e.g on Github). the commits are sorted that the upper one is more recent
- Copy the long `SHA key` of the commit you want to checkout and run `git checkout sha_key`. `sha_key` is the key you just copied

Comment: This is just for checking out to a commit. More steps may be required if you want to do merge, make the commit the most recent etc.

Answer (score 9):

There is an awesome extension called [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) for that:

After installed, go to thee source control tab, right click on the file and select, "Open File History".
Select your commit, then right click over it and click "Restore" from popup menu.

[image]